# SearchView on WebView

Tags: webview, toolbar, searchview

I have a WebView app that pulls the content from my wordpress Ecommerce website so, basically what I want to achieve is to implement SearchView on my WebView app.So,that I can search the products on my WebView app using the SearchView. I don't know how to do it.I have tried something like the code below but, i have failed .Please help me. I am so new at java.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate (R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);
    final SearchView searchView=(SearchView)item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_search);
            String string = "http://xclusiveinterviews.com/search?q=" + searchView;
            mwebView.loadUrl(string);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:title="@string/Search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```